# Excel VBA If row has data, cell cannot be blank

Tags: vba, excel

I have searched for this answer, but can't quite find what I need. I have a document in which users will be pasting data, sometimes up to 5000 rows (that's the limit). It has columns A-AG. Some of the columns are required, some are not. I have been told users may post data with blank rows.

I am trying to work on a macro to alert users to missing data. I will tie this to a user form box. The way I was thinking to tackle this problem would be to loop through rows from 19 (where the data starts) to 5000. If the row has any data, then check the required column.

For example, check row 19, if there is any data, check column F. If data is missing in column F, generate message Box. I hope that makes sense, and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [Range.AutoFilter Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193884.aspx) will all significant fields filtering for blank. Count with Suntotal to see it the filter found anything then delete them.

Comment: If a column is required and has nothing in it, why do you even care what's in the rest of the row?

Comment: @Comintern - If a cell had something in it, and (for instance) a SUM was done on that column, the sum may not be meaningful if that cell was just garbage data without the corresponding compulsory fields completed in other columns.  So it would be quite reasonable to check that the compulsory fields are filled in if the non-compulsory fields were.  (Or, looking it at it the other way around, that none of the non-compulsory fields were filled in if the compulsory fields were not completed.)

Comment: @YowE3K - The  *blank* row is the special case though. It is much, much more efficient to check whether *any* compulsory is missing. If any compulsory field is missing, it's invalid ***unless*** the rest of the row has data.

Comment: @Comintern - No, if a compulsory field is missing it's invalid **if** the rest of the row has data.

Comment: @YowE3K - Ooops, typing too fast - I meant invalid unless the rest of the row has ***no*** data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will check each of the rows from 19 to 5000, see if there is any non-empty cell in the first 33 columns (i.e. A to AG), then check certain cells to make sure that they are **not** empty.  (I arbitrarily decided that columns F, G and J were compulsory.)

```
Sub CheckRows
    Dim r As Long
    Dim c As Long
    'Dim emptyRow As Boolean

    With ActiveSheet
        For r = 19 to 5000
            'Edited based on suggestion by Scott Craner
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 33))) > 0 Then
            'emptyRow = True
            'For c = 1 To 33
            '    If Not IsEmpty(.Cells(r, c)) Then
            '        emptyRow = False
            '        Exit For
            '    End If
            'Next
            'If Not emptyRow Then
                If IsEmpty(.Cells(r, "F")) Or _
                   IsEmpty(.Cells(r, "G")) Or _
                   IsEmpty(.Cells(r, "J")) Then
                    MsgBox "Row " & r & " has some compulsory cells not filled in"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Shouldn't the logic be reversed? [See the comment above](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39301321/excel-vba-if-row-has-data-cell-cannot-be-blank#comment65936604_39301321).

Comment: @Comintern - I **thought** my code was checking to see if there was any data in the row and, if there was, giving an error message if column F, etc, was not filled in.  Now you have me scratching my head because I can't see what is wrong in the code.  Maybe I had better test it.

Comment: There's absolutely nothing *incorrect* about the code, it's just a needlessly inefficient way to approach the problem.

Comment: lol... I guess this is the straight forward way to do this. Pretty much the logic that I came up with as well...

Comment: You could simply use `WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(r,1),.Cells(r,33))>0` to check for an empty row instead of looping through the columns.

Comment: This worked like a charm. Thank you so much, YowE3k!

Comment: @ScottCraner - On second thoughts, I wonder whether the CountA may be less efficient than looking at cells one at a time, given that cell A is probably going to be non-empty in most rows and therefore a cell-by-cell evaluation would only need to look at a single cell, but CountA has to look at all 33 cells.  Given that it is only 5000 rows, it's probably a moot point - even if one method was 10 times faster than the other, it probably only means the difference between 0.01 seconds and 0.1 seconds which a user would never even notice.

Comment: @YowE3K - [See below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39301625/4088852). It's a little clearer in code than comments (+1 BTW).  ;-)

Answer (score 2):

The other answers work, but are less efficient due to having the key rule reversed.  There's no reason to check if a row is empty *unless one of the compulsory fields is missing*.  From your question, the rule is:

> Rows must have all compulsory fields unless they are empty.

This can be restated as:

> If any compulsory field is empty, the entire row must be empty.

The *programming test* for the second is much, much more efficient because you can short-circuit if the first part of the test is true:

```
Sub CheckRows()
    Dim r As Long, c As Long, missingValue As Boolean

    With ActiveSheet
        For r = 1 To 5000
            Select Case True
                Case .Cells(r, "F") = vbNullString:
                    missingValue = True
                Case .Cells(r, "G") = vbNullString:
                    missingValue = True
                Case .Cells(r, "J") = vbNullString:
                    missingValue = True
                Case Else
                    missingValue = False
            End Select
            'This is the ONLY CASE where you need to check if the row is empty.
            If missingValue Then
                If WorksheetFunction.CountA(.Range(.Cells(r, 1), .Cells(r, 33))) > 0 Then
                    MsgBox "Row " & r & " has some compulsory cells not filled in"
                End If
            End If
        Next
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: I'll upvote your answer as it will almost certainly be more efficient (even though it probably won't be noticeable to the user).  But I have a feeling that a lot of less-experienced coders will have trouble understanding exactly what is happening, and therefore will have difficulties adapting it to their own situation if they have a similar issue to the OP.

Comment: @YowE3K - One can only hope not :-)  I think the only non-obvious part should be that the `Select Case` is used to provide the short-circuiting.  I just didn't want to go into the whole `If` doesn't short-circuit in VBA discussion.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking all cells in a row first, and if any data is found, then check the required items. Something like this (my VBA is pretty rusty, so this may not be  copy-pastable, but it should be close):

```
Dim row As Integer, col As Integer, hasData As Boolean
Dim errors() As String, errorText as String

ReDim errors(1 To 1) As String

For row = 19 To 5000
    hasData = False
    ` Check each cell in this row to see if it has data
    For col = 1 To 33
        If IsEmpty(Cells(row, col).Value) = True Then
            hasData = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next col

    If hasData Then

        errorText = ""

        `validate data here for this row
        `set errorText to non-empty if an error found

        If errorText <> "" Then
            errors(UBound(errors)) = errorText
            ReDim Preserve errors(1 To UBound(errors) + 1) As String
        End If
    End If
Next row

`if errors found, join all the errors together and show to user
If UBound(errors) > 1 Then MsgBox Join(errors, vbCrLf)
```